# Winforms design advice

Tags: winforms, panel

I am working on a winforms client server application that will load one of many forms that would be used to enter data or retrieve data or search for data.  I want to put buttons on the left side of the screen to select which form is loaded on the right, and buttons at the top for the usual New, Open, delete etc.

I began working on this by making an MDI form that would popup a child window that allows to user to pick the application they want to use. Then when they select it, it would load the appropriate form on the right and update the text and functions of the buttons on the left.  I was using panels to load the forms into for the button form (which I called the Navigator) and the application form.  I had to use events to make changes to the different button forms when the form on the right was changed. A friend of mine said that I was probably going about this in the wrong way.  He said there is probably a better design pattern or methodology or controls that already do that for me.

I dont know how to even search for something like this on the web.

Can someone give me some direction on this?
I can do the research if I am pointed in the right direction.
Maybe there is a control that already does all this?
Thank You.

Comment: I ended up using a splitpanel vertically with a flowpanel inside of the splitpanel's right side so if a user resizes the window, the controls will auto position themselves. There is an MDI selection screen that picks the overall application and the splitpanel is for that application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use a similar pattern. MDI parent with menus for objects and tasks. MDI Child forms (about 30) for each object/task. Left "nav" button in three groups: 1:1 (calling up l related objects), 1:N (display lists of related objects - inspections, equipment, etc.), N:N:X (other complex relationships or tasks). The body has a tab control to group data. At least one tab is a datagridview that is reused for the 1:N lists.

Left nav button sets are dependent on the object being managed. We add the buttons dynamically but in most case they are hard coded - we just don't use the toolbox to place the buttons on the child forms. Each button set is in a Panel - I would probably use a FlowPanel if I were to start over.

We build a "model" form on one of the more complex objects, built all the data binding logic, and then used that form as a basis for the other objects. We didn't use inheritance as supplied by Visual Studio/VB.Net.

We do our own control data "binding." We use ADO.Net and SQL Server. Our child forms only display one record and do not support the typical record navigation seen in the wizard generated forms - this works fine in our case as we navigate sideways through our data. e.g. Application, Authority to Construct, Permit - then inspections, renewals etc. all related to one Facility. (we're a regulator agency)

We use VB.Net as a lot of the business logic was developed in VB6. I'd still use VB.Net today vs C# - much easier to use for business logic and more maintainable IMO.

One issue to consider - some have out the long knives for WinForms (and VB.Net.) I can't see Microsoft depreciating WinForms but there are those advocating that. Many cannot appreciate the simplicity (albeit limited flexibility) of the WinForms that allows us to concentrate on the business being done. I keep looking at WPF but simply cannot see the usefulness of all the UI power it provides. WPF proponents will push MVVM but that is just more complexity that is not needed for small scale development or production (20 users with desktops o a LAN) environments. WPF does not lead itself to our sideways navigation.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with everything you have said here. `C#` is much more concise than VB.Net, and it's syntax is much more readable. and WPF does not add any "extra complexity", it simplifies development a LOT by allowing DataBinding as opposed to the horrible crappy too-much-code-for-anything winforms code behind approach. WPF views have, most of the time, no code behind at all, and they bind directly to business objects or ViewModels to provide the presentation logic.

Comment: I respectfully AGREE with most everything you commented here. Doesn't change a thing here in my real world. I can't toss close to 100 forms and 10's of thousands of lines of code to chase the latest tool from MS. I have created some smaller supporting apps in WPF + EF (using VB.Net, sorry) and it worked fine for a simple DB. BTW you hurt your credibility by stating the C# is more readable. Concise, perhaps if you are build tools. As to the OP a lot depends on what they are already using, where they are4 going, and the scale. I just posted what we were up to and described the environment.

Comment: it's ok if you don't want to throw your existing work, but it's completely untrue that WPF "adds more complexity". Also, if you objectively [compare C# to VB.Net](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Visual_Basic_.NET), you'll quickly realize that VB.Net means "more text", because it lacks the `{` and `}` syntax, and introduces the `End ...` syntax (such as `End If`, `End For`), etc. Also, the VB.Net lambda expression syntax is really convoluted, as opposed to C#'s simple `() =>` or `x => x...`

Comment: If one thinks like a compiler C# is the way to go for sure. If you think like a human I'm not so sure. Less characters <> readability. I think the WiKi article compares the readability issues nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I think the left toolbar for selecting the form is a good pattern, but make it collapsible (hide) so the user could use all the desktop space.

As for MDI personally I don't like it because fell a bit outdated and cluttered. But again look for a balance of form and function.

For the top toolbar I would make it part of each form so it would be easy to program the logic. It an unnecesary complication put them on the master form.

As a recomendation you could look, [Designing Web Interfaces](http://designingwebinterfaces.com/explore) even it's more focussed to web could give some pointers in user interaction.

For more informacion search **ui patterns**, **user interaction design**.